# Purpose of TRAN and COMMIT in single/multiple SQL INSERT SELECT UPDATE DELETE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can someone please explain to me in simple layman words what the SQL transaction is doing here?

**Here is the scenario**:
I am not SQL developer or data engineer. I wish to update column value depending on a filter that you see in where clause. I ran the query in database as I do have an admin rights, it was with approvals of course.

**I typed in below command as per my need**.

```
update idx_task set IDXTaskStatusDE=4 where ID='task_ID'
```

**The developer then sent to me the following query and said I was doing the wrong way.**

```
Use Works
    begin tran
    update idx_task set IDXTaskStatusDE=4 where ID='task_ID'
    commit tran
```

**Developer's email response**:
When issuing adhoc statements directly against SQL, it is a good idea to wrap your statements in a transaction, just in case something goes wrong and you need to rollback. Updating the same table twice would be different than with or without the transaction. Hence, this is a professional practice which can be unknown to amateurs like you. This job seems to be outside your primary role. Please discuss with your boss and get your team a profession SQL developer.

**My Efforts**:
Hence, I am here after reading technical jargon to get in few words or with example how both queries would act differently anyway.

**My Question:**
1.) Can someone please provide a simple theoretical explanations of difference here, of significance of wrapping the single update statement in tran? 
2.) is it for any prior, future, safety or professional practices in SQL developers community?

**Thank you note to all saviours here**
Thanks in advance to all types of responses. Your any type of feedback shall help me gain knowledge anyways :)

Take Care !!

Comment: What part(s) of this do you not understand?

Comment: this is straightforward. it sets TaskStatusDE to 4 to all transactions whose ID is "task_ID"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question can be answered by consulting product documentation or any available online tutorial. There is no need for a Stack Overflow question on this topic.

Comment: @KaustubhUrsekar If you look into any SQL tutorial (not just SQL Server) you'll find out what those statements do. SO isn't a discussion forum. It's a Q&A site about specific programming questions. You didn't ask a question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did not knew that, Thanks a lot for letting me know this. I wont be here next time with such type of questions.

Comment: @EricBrandt I did not know the in depth standard of this site. It seems that it is for well developed professional coders only Sorry, if this has not met your standards. Kindly ignore this question. Thanks for letting me know this :)

Comment: @Oasa Maybe I was not clear when I first posted this, please see again and let me know your thoughts. If this question is below your standards, please ignore it. Thanks again :)

Comment: @SeanLange Please refer the question again as I was not clear previously. Apologizing for inconvinience. If still this question seems below your standards, kindly ignore. Thanks a lot again. take care ! :)

Comment: @KaustubhUrsekar the question is still unlcear - unless the developer doesn't know SQL. `UPDATE` is atomic - either everything succeeds or everything fails. It doesn't need to be wrapped in `begin tran/commit tran` calls. It already acts as if it were wrapped in them

Comment: But that's the point - UPDATE is atomic. If something goes wrong it will roll back immediately. The only reason to put those BEGIN/COMMIT is when *you* want to keep the transaction open, eg to check the results, and decide whether to commit or roll back manually. The problem with this is that while the transaction is open, the rows are locked and other connections that try to modify them get blocked. Everyone forgets to call `COMMIT` once in a while, and remembers it when coworkers start complaining

Comment: Another issue is, that as far as the database is concerned, applications or even different SSMS windows are just different connections. They won't see the changes you made inside a transaction until it's committed. So using BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT TRAN is only useful when you want to check your modifications in the same window. There's no way around this, you just need to be carefult to call COMMIT or ROLLBACK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208266/discussion-between-kaustubh-ursekar-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this question's thread. It will clear your confusion.
[Using transaction on a single update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369619/using-transaction-on-a-single-update-statement)

**@Panagiotis Kanavos** has pointed out and articulated perfectly.

Just know the simple meaning of following term while you read in regards to SQL Transactions:

1.) Atomic: "Atomic" means "cannot be divided or split in smaller parts". Applied to 1NF this means that a column should not contain more than one value. It should not compose or combine values that have a meaning of their own.

2.) Commit: A COMMIT statement in SQL ends a transaction within a relational database management system (RDBMS) and makes all changes visible to other users.

3.) Lock: Is a mechanism to ensure data consistency. SQL Server locks objects when the transaction starts. When the transaction is completed, SQL Server releases the locked object. Hence, in your case as pointed out by @Panagiotis Kanavos, the TRAN is doing the work of blocking all other commands if executed by other developers working in parallel to the same data that you are executing your UPDATE statement on.

Hope this helps. I do not think there would be more going down as "simple words" than this. Still feel free to ask if you still have a confusion.